# Tools For Code Performance in .Net And C#

Tags: c#, performance

For Example You know foreach loop is heavy And if we use for loop is Better.

What Tools Can Help me to Write Code With Best Performance In C Sharp net,And Check My Code for this?

Please Help me

**Edit ::**

**I Want A Tools To Convert my Code To Best Performance Code.For Example When I Compile My C Sharp Code To IL Code,This Tools Convert foreach loop to for loop For Best Performance.**

Comment: I question your initial assertion that for loops are always better than foreach loops...

Comment: The best tool for that sort of conversion is a smart programmer. Armed with a profiler.

Comment: `foreach` should always generate the most efficient loop. The optimisation is built into the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Redgate's performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) is a great tool for this, which has a free 14-day trial.

[Jetbrain's profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) is also very good.

Comment: these are both good tools, worth paying for

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for performance optimization is a good profiler.  The profiler will show you what parts of your code take the longest to execute.  You can then focus your efforts where they will do the most good.  Visual Studio 2010 (I think Professional and up) has a very good profiler in the box.  I also like Red-Gate ANT profiler and JetBrain's dotTrace.

Answer (score 1):

Keyword: Profiler. A profiler executes your code and helps you discovering performance-lacks by measuring.

Best one for .NET is:
http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html?dt30pr

Microsoft also has a program to analize your .NET assemblies (not by measuring) but by reflecting in order to detect performancecosting coding habits (e.g. defining more than 64 variables in a method block):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The tool you need is called Profiler. I like dotTrace Profiler (Google it). btw, foreach loop is not heavy it self.